# script for auto-downloading file from FTP

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I need a simple script which will download file/files from my external FTP server.

I tried to run it in a batch file, but it didn't work:

```
ftp yourftpaddress

user yourusername

yourpassword

get yourfile.type

bye

pause
```

I need it for Windows 7

Comment: Please update your question with what you are currently trying along with the specific issues/errors you are getting. We won't just write you a functioning script when you show no research or attempt.

Comment: What was the result of running this? Please copy and paste the output and describe how it is not the desired result.

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO it is not a free coding service. Make some research and when you have any doubt, we will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this PowerShell script for downloading files from an FTP Server

```
#ftp server 
$ftp = "ftp://example.com/" 
$usernmae = "XX" 
$password = "XXX"
$SetType = "bin"  
$remotePickupDir = Get-ChildItem 'c:\test' -recurse
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)  
foreach($item in $remotePickupDir){ 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
    #$webclient.UploadFile($uri,$item.FullName)
    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri,$item.FullName)
}
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me, i get just many of red code. Maybe i do something wrong?

Comment: #ftp server $ftp = "172.48.34.103" $username = "mYuseRnamE" $password = "mYuseRpassworD" $SetType = "bin" $remotePickupDir = Get-ChildItem 'path of file which i need to download' -recurse $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password) foreach($item in $remotePickupDir){ $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) #$webclient.UploadFile($uri,$item.FullName) $webclient.DownloadFile($uri,$item.FullName) }